Plausibility of the Yale
So, recently I've been struggling to create a bestiary that includes mythical medieval creatures, but trying to make them as plausible as possible.
Recently I've been struggling with one in particular, the Yale, an ungulate creature with horns that possess the ability to swivel in any direction which makes them good for both offensive and defensive attacks (extract from Wikipedia).
I was thinking of making them have a thick skull with strong tendons and ligaments that allow them to move the horns up and down and call it a day, but since I'm working the ecology of the creature backwards and having the design first, now I'm struggling to justify what kind of evolutionary pressure could there be in order to justify such a weird and niche adaptation, so my question is as follows:
What kind of enviromental pressure could make a member of the artiodactyla order develop articulated horns instead of regular ones, assuming they'd have enough energy to develop and mantain such a niche adaptation in the first place?

For future reference, please understand that asking more than one question is literally a reason to close questions. You're asking two. Your title asks for "plausibility" and your body asks for an "environmental pressure." They're not the same thing.

Understood, sorry. I still struggle a bit with english and sometimes I don't get the phrasing well.

Looking at the yale from a science-based perspective, the horn articulation has problems.
If the horns are straight and simply tilt backwards and forwards so as to point their sharp tips forward for offensive use or backwards for defensive use, the problem comes from the fact that the horns are no longer a part of the skull, but now freely articulate from the skull.  It would be concievable to use them as a thrusting weapon by pointing their tips in the right direction, but when used defensively, they would be relying upon the strength of the muscles that move them rather than the strength and flexibility of bone and horn to absorb blows.
Consider... if you have a single-plane 'knee joint' that allows the horns to tilt to point forwards or backwards, the joint becomes a weak point, and a lateral force on the horn could result in damage to the joint.
If you have an omnidirectional ball joint, the horn can move and rotate in any direction without injury, but it's going to take a lot of muscle to compensate for the strength and flexibility of a fixed horn.  The resultant yale wouldn't look much like an antelope, with its head swollen with muscle for moving and pointing its horns.
There is also a third possibility: a 'pin-and-socket' joint, that to my knowledge doesn't occur in nature, but could.  Such a joint would allow the cylindrical base of the horn (the pin) to fit within a cylindrical socket in the skull, and the animal's muscles simply rotate the curved horn to point backwards or forwards, which seems to be the way the creature was described in Pliny the Elder's Natural History (volume VIII).  With a sufficiently large pin and socket joint, such an arrangement of horns might be marginally practical, though large muscles to rotate and hold the horns would still be required, and the joint would still be a weak point that could be more easily injured.
The problem comes when we try to evolve such a thing.  One of the principles of evolution is that each intermediate step between not having a trait at all and having the full trait is that all the intermediate steps have to be more advantageous than the previous steps.
With these rotating horns, we run into the problem that if the animal possessed fixed horns, how can any intermediate step between fixed horns and fully mobile pin and socket horns be advantageous?  Try as I might, I can't help but think that the intermediate steps would be disadvantageous.  This is a case of "You can't get there from here."
What if we went down a different route?  What if the precursor animal didn't have horns at all?  We could have an animal that instead of evolving bony horn-covered extensions of its skull, evolved as bundles of compressed and fused hair that could be moved with dermal muscles as a signalling device.  As the animal evolved, the fused hair became more solid and keratinous as rhinoceros horn is, and grew with a characteristic curve.  As these signalling horns grew larger, with a better range for their use as semaphore devices, they would require stronger joints to support them... until the point where they had become big enough that when angled correctly, they could be used offensively or defensively in mating struggles, depending upon their orientation.  With these uses, the pin and socket joints and the associated muscles would evolve to be stronger to allow this altered function.
So, TL,DR: we can evolve yales... but not from an already-horned species, but from one that evolved its 'horns' as a mobile semaphore device that as they grew larger and more capable, were repurposed into offensive and defensive weapons... and can still be used for their original purpose of semaphore.

Thank you very much for your answer. So, these horns would be entirely keratinous, no bone core?

@GeorgeWatson That's up to you... the horns could be ossified, or they could be entirely keratinous like rhino horns.  They're more likely ossified, though.

mammals already have tiny sets of "horns" on their head that can be moved in a very articulated way by muscles: the eyebrows. One can imagine a creature that first evolved very long eyebrows as a sort of  mating display "whiskers" which then became longer and longer, and more rigid (likely due to sexual competition: peacock-style) until they turned into semaphor-like horns. Basically imagine a male elk wiggling its eyebrows sexily at a female to dazzle her, and his progeny evolving more and more impressive brow ornaments to display their masculine virility.

It is quite possible for a yale like species to be created by biological science.  And that would probably be much more likely to happen than for the species to evolve naturally.
So possibly your world is one where some super advance society decided to create creatures similar to those in medieval imagination.
